# Error during WebSocket handshake

Tags: java, netbeans, websocket

I am trying to follow the instructions given in [this tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-websocketapi.html) and create a sample application in Netbeans. I have reached till the testing part. When I run the application in chrome it says

> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://localhost:8080/WhiteboardApp/whiteboardendpoint' failed: Error
>   during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Start Page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Collaborative Whiteboard App</h1>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="websocket.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**websocket.js**

```
var wsUri = "ws://" + document.location.host + document.location.pathname + "whiteboardendpoint";
var websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };

function onError(evt) {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
}

// For testing purposes
var output = document.getElementById("output");
websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };

function writeToScreen(message) {
    output.innerHTML += message + "<br>";
}

function onOpen(evt) {
    writeToScreen("Connected to " + wsUri);
}
// End test functions
```

**MyWhiteboard.java**

```
package org.myapps.whiteboardapp;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/whiteboardendpoint ")
public class MyWhiteboard {
    private static Set<Session> peers = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message) {
        return null;
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen (Session peer) {
        peers.add(peer);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose (Session peer) {
        peers.remove(peer);
    }
}
```

Where have I gone wrong ? How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: The only change I from the tutorial is that while creating the project I used package as 'org.myapps.whiteboardapp' instead of 'org.sample.whiteboardapp'. But that is not the cause of the problem I suppose

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid server annotation

Fix this

```java
@ServerEndpoint("/whiteboardendpoint ")
```

To

```java
@ServerEndpoint("/whiteboardendpoint") /* removed space */
```

The way you have it defined currently, you could probably just change your javascript `wsUri` definition to ...

```
var wsUri = "ws://" + document.location.host + document.location.pathname +
            "whiteboardendpoint%20";
var websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

and have it work. (just added a URI encoded space)